# Video streaming API

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, security, restriction

Current situation: Users are downloading the whole video clip (>70mb or >140mb).  This is not as effective as we would like.

[I am a non programmer looking for a solution]... I want to be able to stream video for a professional development package from our servers to the user.  The user logs in and access the video from the dashboard.  I wanted to use Youtube Api for this, but we are apprehensive in using it as we cannot dissallow others that aren't in the subscription to view it.

Does any one recommend a solution for this problem i can give to our programming team?

thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

- Adobe provides [some sort of server solution](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/fvss/) that you can host
- You can try contacting [one of these guys](http://www.flashcomguru.com/articles/hosts.cfm), who will host it for you and such.

Or, if you have half decent non-outsourced techies, just ask one of them.  Use whatever they are most comfortable with.  Delegating is ok :)

Comment: Thanks for the adobe solution will definitely look into it! 

The issue is that they have not implimented a good solution. They have provided a solution that requires the user to download the entire video before it plays.. So I want to provide them (the techies) a solution that is better for our customers.

Comment: What I mean is to allow them to use the server solution, if they can set it up.  If not, then recommend an outsourced one, so someone else gets to do the annoying work and such.  Honestly, without extra software there isn't much they *could* have done.  Will you let them buy something, or were you expecting they would write it?